# c# jquery Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a webservice in c# and I am calling it from my jquery script.

This is the webservice in c#

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public void LoadService2Daily(string fromDate, string toDate, string[] campaigns)
```

In script I do this:

```
var selectedCampaigns = $("#campaignDiv input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    console.log(selectedCampaigns);


webServiceUrl = 'http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadService2Daily';
$.getJSON(webServiceUrl,
      { fromDate: valFrom, toDate: valTo, campaigns: selectedCampaigns })
       .done(function (result) {
```

I got **error 500** and when I check the response, it is **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

#### Note

If I removed the `string[] array` from the web service, it works perfectly, but when I add it, it stoped working. so I am sure it is because the `string array` thing but I don't know where exactly is the mistake.

The code without the array have been working for 3 years without any problem, but now I am making some editing and I need to pass that array.

This is a screenshot of the `console.log` to print the selectedCampgains. Notice that, as I showed you in the code, this log is taken before calling the web service

[image]

#### Edit

I noticed that the url of the web service is

```
Request URL:http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadService2Daily?fromDate=2014-05-25+00%3A00%3A00&toDate=2014-05-25+23%3A59%3A01&campaigns%5B%5D=default&campaigns%5B%5D=Support
```

as it doesn't contain the string array, right?

#### Edit3

This is the whole exception that I get

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @SonerGönül it is not a null exception, the main problem is the `500` error.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through the code of the webservice to find out exactly where the error is being raised?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I already did that. but no break point executes which indicates that the web service is not called at all. I think that I am calling it wrong. right?

Comment: There is a lot going on in the selectedCampaigns  variable. What is the result of the selectedCampaigns before you pass it into the server side method? Use a browser debugger to take a peek at the info. Consider something like fiddler as well to see what message is being passed to the server

Comment: Can you switch to using POST and use Firebug / Chrome dev tools to examine the request being sent to the server? It _shouldn't_ make a difference but arrays are a bit of a tricky one as they're not officially defined in the HTTP spec (IIRC). Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: The argument appears in order. Are you able to see the set the breakpoint in your handler?If it is not breaking rebuild and republish. the code in your IDE needs to be the code that is running on your server.

Comment: @Basic I already did that though it is get not post. this is the request Request URL:http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadService2Daily?fromDate=2014-05-25+00%3A00%3A00&toDate=2014-05-25+23%3A59%3A01&campaigns%5B%5D=default&campaigns%5B%5D=Support

Comment: @manuelhe I put break point in the first line in the method but it is not executed. i tried clean and restart but nothing works

Comment: You'll have to move up the chain to find a point where you can step through

Comment: @manuelhe it is a web service, so you call it as methods

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yeah so the %5B and %5D in `campaigns%5B%5D=Support¬ there are `[]` which is the generally accepted way of doing arrays (`campaigns[]=Value1&campaigns[]=Value2`). For testing purposes, can you please create a POCO model to use instead of raw values in the LoadService2Daily method signature? Basically create a class with properties matching your parameters and use that in the function instead... `public void LoadService2Daily(MyNewPOCOModel Data)`

Comment: @Basic No I can't do that because this web service is integrated with many other systems in the company and all they can do is adding the new string array to their requests.

Comment: 2 Reasons for the request, first is debugging - you should not get a 500 error, you should get an object with some null properties which we can examine (and more importantly, examine the model binder for). Secondly, it won't actually change the signature of the method. You'd still pass in exactly the same parameters

Comment: @Basic what can I do please? the method is not invoke, the request is correct, the method declaration is correct. can you access my machine using team viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL which is being generated has square brackets, can you please check whether this will work without square brackets i.e without %5B and %5D(without url encoding)

```
http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadService2Daily?fromDate=2014-05-25+00%3A00%3A00&toDate=2014-05-25+23%3A59%3A01&campaigns=default&campaigns=Support
```

Comment: please tell me what did you do and how to fix the problem, you maject url works, but what should I do in my request to avoid these stuff that you have removed ?

Comment: please give me an example, I really don't know.

Comment: I will accept your answer now, +1 please could u complete your answer in my this new question about the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859946/jquery-remove-strange-characters-from-the-array

Comment: OK I'll be doing that for you