# jquery remove strange characters from the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array and I am sending it to a web service,

the url is this

```
http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadService2Daily?fromDate=2014-05-26+00%3A00%3A00&toDate=2014-05-26+23%3A59%3A01&campaigns%5B%5D=default&campaigns%5B%5D=Support
```

that url doesn't work and return 500 internal error

but when I remove the `%5B%5D`, the url becomes this:

```
http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadService2Daily?fromDate=2014-05-25+00%3A00%3A00&toDate=2014-05-25+23%3A59%3A01&campaigns=default&campaigns=Support
```

and it works perfectly.

what are these strange characters and how to remove them please?

The array is the `selectedCampains` and I am sending it like this:

```
$.getJSON(webServiceUrl,
      { fromDate: valFrom, toDate: valTo, campaigns: selectedCampaigns })
```

I get that array in this way:

```
var selectedCampaigns = $("#campaignDiv input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    console.log(selectedCampaigns);
```

Comment: Can you post the array itself? It may be that you need to .join() the array. :)

Comment: `%5B%5D` is the string `[]`, [urlencoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: @JakeSidSmith when I conslog.log the array I got this `["default", "Support"]`

Comment: I think you need to join the array by comma selectedCampaigns.join(',') with should give you a string like: "default, Support"

Comment: @JakeSidSmith let me try and I will update you

Comment: Like tbrisker said, it is not handling the array characters properly. :)

Comment: @JakeSidSmith I made selectedCampaigns.join(',') and that didn't works

Comment: What did the URL look like after that?

Comment: I'm gonna assume it was just "campaigns=default,Support" at the end?

Comment: @JakeSidSmith no it didn't change. this is it again http://localhost:4025/vmp_webservice.asmx/LoadService2Daily?fromDate=2014-05-26+00%3A00%3A00&toDate=2014-05-26+23%3A59%3A01&campaigns%5B%5D=default&campaigns%5B%5D=direct

Comment: Woops, didn't realise that was a JQuery array... Was it the same in the console as before?

Comment: @JakeSidSmith yes the same

Comment: Seems that user3672923 has a solution. Sorry I couldn't be more use. ^_^

Comment: @JakeSidSmith yes he is the best user ever, he answered me before and now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, these are the square brackets and it has to parsed and removed from URL:

```
var sc = JSON.stringify(selectedCampaigns);
```

pass this sc where you're trying to pass `selectedCampaigns` as an array.

Comment: you are the best user ever, I will keep watching you to upvot your answers. thanks really 100000000 thanks

Comment: Don't 'keep watching...to [upvote] answers,' you run the risk of having any serial votes removed by the [serial-voting/vote-fraud script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). Obviously upvote useful answers, but *don't* just run through and upvote everything at once.

Comment: I found that your code makes the array as string, one string. I don't need that , I need it to keep array. is that possible ?